# Find .xls file with an applet running in Plone

Tags: java, resources, applet, plone

I'm working on an Applet to be run inside a Plone website.
In one of the pages managed by Plone I have to run this applet, which does the following steps:

- advanced form validation
- takes an excel template on the server hard disk and copies it with some of the data appended as name (like calcoloOneri.xls becomes calcoloOneriJohnFileOne.xls)
- writes form data into the newly created file
- sends this file to a webservice I created to convert the excel into a PDF
- lets the users download the pdf on their machine

Now the problem is that since I may have multiple intances of various websites different only for the name and little other things, I parameterized my applet to be run into each of these different scenarios.
Particular attention I have given to the location of the template.xls file, which may vary according to site structure/file name necessities.
The code that loads the applet is the following (taken from a loaded page):

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>var user='admin'</script>
<script>var comune='Andria'</script>
<script>var numPratica=''</script>
<script>var numPreinoltro='20482109022013'</script>
<script>var classifica=''</script>
<script>var numFascicolo=''</script>
<script>var annoFascicolo=''</script>
<script>var portalURL='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/scia2'</script>
<script>
  var attributes = {code:'geotel.gui.Login.class', archive:'portal_url/++resource++java/GestioneOneri.jar, portal_url/++resource++java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar, portal_url/++resource++java/poi-3.8-20120326.jar, portal_url/++resource++java/forms-1.3.0.jar', width:1024, height:700};
  var parameters = {jnlp_href:'portal_url/++resource++java/gestioneoneri.jnlp', nomeUtente:user, integrato:'true', portalUrl:portalURL, comune:comune, percorsoFileCalcoloOneri:'/++resource++java/', nomeFileCalcoloOneri:'calcoloOneri.xls', numPreinoltro:numPreinoltro, numPratica:numPratica, classifica:classifica, numFascicolo:numFascicolo, annoFascicolo:annoFascicolo};
  var version = '1.6';
  deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
<noscript>
Niente plugin java!
</noscript>
```

As I read from the Plone documentation, the ++resource++ syntax lets the CMS to retrieve static resources registered in xml registries, and I have no problem using it into plone .pt files.

So, after all that reading, I head to my browser and write:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/scia2/++resource++java/calcoloOneri.xls
```

and Chrome downloads the file calcoloOneri.xls, so I think "I must be on the right track".

The problems arise when I pass these values into my applet. First of all, since I can have multiple sites running this applet, I get the address of the website as a parameter (portalUrl). To retrieve the location of the excel file I append ++resource++java/calcoloOneri.xls to the portal url, because in the browser this address is correct.

In my copyFile method I use the following objects to copy the excel template into a new one:

```
File f1 = new File(srFile); //srFile is "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/scia2/++resource++java/calcoloOneri.xls"
File f2 = new File(dtFile);
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
{
   out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

I have experienced on my skin that java.io.File cannot handle this kind of url, nor I can get a pointer to that file using an URL or an URI object in my applet code.

How can I get the correct string to read the template into my applet? What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off doing it all in python with the xlwt library for modifying excel documents. Then, it could be a simple web form. The excel template could be a File content type object so you'd just grad the file data from there instead of doing a remote call.

Otherwise, a way you could do it is to hard code the path to the excel template file.

If you want to download the file from a url, a google search can help: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Download_a_file_from_a_URL_in_Java-17947.html

However you solve it, be careful in the implementation as accepting user-submitted values to be downloaded from the internet can be dangerous.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I don't want to do it in python because I need to perform operations already implemented in the Java applet. The problem is not in the download method, which I know how to do, but in the identification of the path from the ++resource++ syntax to a full standard path on the hard disk. I already hard coded the path, but it's very very prone to errors this way..

Comment: There is no way to know the file system path from a ++resource++ file in Java from a running python server. If there was, it'd be a security risk.